# Resilience4j with spring boot

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-boot, resilience4j-retry

Earlier, i used CircuitBreaker and Retry annotations with void method. It worked.
But Timelimiter was not working.

@Timelimiter(name = "example_tl")

@CIRCUITBREAKER(name = "example_cb", fallbackMethod = "sendDataFallBack")

@Retry(name = "example_retry", fallbackMethod = "sendDataFallBack")

public void methodData(JsonObject jsondata)

I read that it is only supported with Reactive methods.

So, i changed my method return type to Mono. After this, nothoing is working.

public Mono..ClientResponse.. methodData(JsonObject jsondata)

Can you please help me here ? (I am stuck)

Regards,
Stephan